# Saving a large heap dump of an IIS process on Windows 2008 64 bit

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, memory, profiling

I just tried creating a heap dump of an IIS process that was taking 6 gigs of RAM (taskmgr, right click, Create Dump File). I got the follow error, and the dump file was corrupt:

> only part of a readprocessmemory or
>   writeprocessmemory request was
>   completed

Did anyone encounter this? Know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if it failed to read some of the process memory and bailed out (which would result in a corrupt dump file). If you attach to the process with windbg, you could run a `.dump /mA` command to make it continue on even if it gets an error reading the process memory.  [Here is a description of the option.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562428.aspx)

Comment: I tried to download windbg, and got to this page, which required .Net framework 4, which I didn't want to install on said computer. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en

Comment: @ripper234, I believe the install itself will still run even without the framework; it just won't install all the pieces.  But it will still install the debuggers, which is the good part.  I believe you can also install it on another machine and just copy in the folder containing windbg.exe to the target machine and run it.  I haven't tried that with the latest versions, but I know that worked with older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) from Microsoft TechNet. It's a standalone executable written by the people who authored [Windows Internals](http://tinyurl.com/23seaj8).